# jquery loop with animation, how to wait until next query

Tags: jquery

how to wait for next loop? i mean when we have loop with animation how to wait untill previously animation end than go for next one?

```
$("#showMore").on('click', function(){
            childs = $("#subPW").children().length;
            console.log(childs);
            for(i=0;i<childs;i++){
                $("#subPW p:eq("+i+")").show(1200);
            }
        })
```

I would like to wait until p element will be displayed then go for next one.. now everything goes in 1 step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is jQuery's [delay](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) method to build up increased delays for each element:

```js
$("#showMore").on('click', function() {
  const $p = $('#subPW').children();
  const time = 1200;

  for (i = 0; i < $p.length; i++) {
    $p.eq(i).delay(i * time).show(time);
  }
})
```

```css
p {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="showMore">Show More</button>
<div id="subPW">
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
</div>
```